# What is an efficient way of keeping a list of data synchronized over a network?

Tags: python, design-patterns, network-programming

I'm building a server-to-many-listeners application where the server has a "master list" that changes many times per second, and these updates need to be streamed to connected clients, so that they can keep a state identical to the server's.

The list contains pricing data, representing an orderbook from an asset exchange and looks like this:

```
[[1.0, 0.002], [1.1, 1.2039], [1.2, 0.29183]]
```

...where the first value is the price, and the second is the amount.

The idea would be that the client would receive the full list upon first connecting (or by some other side-channel), and would then incrementally apply the changes as they stream in.

Is there a pattern for doing this sort of thing? Efficiency is important here (but 2nd to correctness), so preferably the amount of data transferred is kept to a minimum.

**EDIT**: I'm less interested in the transport layer and more in the data layer, how to structure the delta format, etc.

Comment: Maybe look at a pubsub architecture (pretty much the observer pattern via a hub) so your server only has to publish once - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish–subscribe_pattern) . I don't have experience with it, but Redis has an implementation and there's an interesting chat POC linked at the bottom of the page here: https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Comment: Is the data only flowing from the master server to the clients?

Comment: @LiamKelly Yes, it's only one-way. The central server is always the source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Upon first glance my instinct is to go with the `Observer Pattern`. From Wikipedia:

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.

In your case the `Master List` is the `Subject` and your `Connected Clients` are your `Listeners`. Every time the `Subject` updates, it then notifies the `Listeners` a change has occurred. This could be as simple as CRUD commands to keep data transfer at a minimum.

**Caveat** - The `Observer Pattern` has been known to cause issues when scaling out with regards to `Listeners`.

Observer Pattern Wikipedia Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern